# Wait for Observable to finish

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, observable, angular2-observables

I am returning Observables from promises

First this one that returns a translation

```js
    translateAction(t): Observable<any>{
      const params = {
        Text: t,
        SourceLanguageCode: "en",
        TargetLanguageCode: "es"
      };
      let actionPromise = this.translate.translator.translateText(params).promise();
          let observe = Observable.fromPromise(
            actionPromise.then((data) => {
              return (data.TranslatedText);
            }).catch((err) => {
              console.log(err);
              return err;
            })
          );
          return observe;
    }
```

and I want to save that text into storage and return the translation (else block)

```js
     let st = this.storage.get("translationCache");
     let observeSt = Observable.fromPromise(
       st.then((val) => {
         console.log("alo?49");
          if(val && val.hasOwnProperty(value)){
            let v = value;

              console.log("Encontrado en memoria:");
              console.log(val[v]);

              return val[v];

          }else{
                console.log("alo?60");
                let v = value;
                let textT = this.translateAction(v).subscribe(t => {
                  textT = t;
                  if(val === null){
                    val = {};
                  }
                  val = Object.assign(val, {[v] : textT});
                    this.storage.set('translationCache', val);
                    console.log("traduccion añadida");
                    console.log(v + ":" + textT);
                  return textT;
                },err => {console.log(err)}); return textT;
              }
            })
         );

         return observeSt;
```

**Expected Behaviour:** Save text in storage and then return the translation.

**Current Behaviour:** Saving the data after a while, but returning [Object Object] since it is not waiting for the translated text

Answer (score 0):

The line `let textT = this.translateAction(v).subscribe(...` assigns a subscription to `textT` then the very next line `return textT;` returns that subscription. Only later does the `textT` get reassigned to a translated string. Whatever method that 2nd block of code is needs to be asynchronous ie return and Observable, Promise, or have a callback. Like possibly:

```js
doStuff(): Observable<any> {
  ...
  let v = value;
  return this.translateAction(v).pipe(
    tap({
      next: t => {
        let textT = t;
        if (val === null) {
          val = {};
        }
        val = Object.assign(val, { [v]: textT });
        this.storage.set('translationCache', val);
        console.log("traduccion añadida");
        console.log(v + ":" + textT);
      },
      error: err => { console.log(err) }
    })
  );
}
```

`doStuff()` returns an Observable

Comment: Sorry I think I missed something important, all that is inside a promise from `storage.get` and it returns an Observable from promise, I'm going to edit the code in the question. I tried it this way, but it is not getting save in storage now, it is just displaying [Object Object]